# The Monthly Cost of the Third House Given the Total Rent Receipts of 186,390 in a Year.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, word-problem

[image]

This is how I solved this problem but I have some reservations regarding my answer.

1st house = x ; 2nd house = 3x ; 3rd house = [3x + x] - 2610

12(x) + 12(3x) + 12(4x - 2610) = 186,390

96x = 155,070

x = 1615.3125

__

4(1615.3125) - 2610 = 3,851.25

I answered 'none of the above'. Is my solution correct? How about my answer? Did I miss something? If there is some kind of shortcut in answering this problem, please let me know.

PS  I am a college student having troubles with word problems.

Comment: You missed the part about the 1st house being vacant for 6 months.

Comment: But the problem states that "otherwise, rents were received every month from the tenants of the three houses" just after the statement that the first house was vacant for 6 months. So does that mean that instead of 12(x), I should make it 6(x)?

Comment: Try it, see what happens.

Comment: I lost the decimal, but it didn't sum up to 186,390.

Comment: What do you mean, "it didn't sum up to 186390"?

Comment: I mean the total rent receipts Arnold has in that year. Wouldn't all rent payments in 3 houses sum up to 186,390?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Let the rent for each house be A, B and C for the House 1, 2 and 3 respectively.
Therefore,
3A = B
C = A + B - 2610

It is also given that only 6 months' rent is collected from the tenant of House 1.
Therefore,
186390 = 12[A + B - 2610] + 36A + 6A
186390 = 90A - 31320
A = 2419;

B=7257

Therefore C = 7066(which would correspond to none of the above).

Answer (score 0):

Your system of equations is:

$y=3x$,
$z=4x-2,610$,
$6x+12y+12z=186,390$,

where $x$ is the first house's monthly rent and $y$, $z$ are the monthly rents for the second and the third house respectively.

Putting the first two equations into third and doing the calculations, gives
$x=2,419$.

Then, substituting this value of $x$ into the second equation gives $z=7,066$.